# The "SMTP connect() failed" insisted even if I used TLS, enabled SMTPAuth and SMTPAutoTLS, and both the ports 25 and 465. I use HotsGator

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, phpmailer

It used to work before, until today that the client contacted me that there is still SMTP failure error.

I have investigated the errors, using `SMTPDebug` with both 1 and 2, and read PHPMailer's Troubleshooting Wiki, but it wasn't helpful:

```
2020-11-24 00:20:42 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2020-11-24 00:20:42 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

It is well known on Stack Overflow. I tried many ways, following the answers of several questions related to it.

After switching to `TLS` on `[NameOfPage]Controller.php`, the error is different:

```
2020-11-24 00:17:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 2020-11-24 00:17:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2020-11-24 00:17:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 2020-11-24 00:17:15 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 2020-11-24 00:17:15 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected 2020-11-24 00:17:15 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 2020-11-24 00:17:15 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

- I use HostGator;
- It is an MVC PHPMailer within an environment;
- PHPMailer is installed via Composer;

All the tests that I made on both files `Mail.php` and `MailController.php` (also `OrcamentoController.php`):

- I tried to enable and disable `SMTPAuth` and `SMTPAutoTLS`, using TLS and port 25;
- I tried to enable and disable `SMTPAuth` and `SMTPAutoTLS`, using TLS and the port 465;
- I tried to enable and disable `SMTPAuth` and `SMTPAutoTLS`, using SSL and port 25;
- I tried to enable and disable `SMTPAuth` and `SMTPAutoTLS`, using SSL and the port 465;
- I updated the Composer and its packages and tried all these tests above and the same errors;
- I switched from the mail host from `mail.thproducoes.com` to `br726.hostgator.com.br` as HostGator has suggested, made all the tests above and the same errors.

I will show only three files.

The complete `Mail.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use App\Contracts\IMail;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use Exception;
use stdClass;

class Mail
{
    private PHPMailer $mail;
    private stdClass $data;
    private Exception $error;

    public function __construct(string $lang = "br")
    {
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $this->data = new stdClass();

        $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true;
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $this->mail->Host = $_ENV['MAIL_HOST'];
        $this->mail->Port = $_ENV['MAIL_PORT'];
        $this->mail->Username = $_ENV['MAIL_USER'];
        $this->mail->Password = $_ENV['MAIL_PASSWORD'];
        
        
        $this->mail->isHTML(true);
        $this->mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
        $this->mail->setLanguage($lang);
        
        $this->mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    }

    public function setCredentials($username, $password): self
    {
        $this->mail->Username = $username;
        $this->mail->Password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setSMTPSecure(string $secure): self
    {
        $this->data->SMTPSecure = $secure;
        return $this;
    }

    public function add(
        string $subject,
        string $body,
        string $recipientName,
        string $recipientEmail
    ): self 
    {
        $this->data->subject = $subject;
        $this->data->body = $body;
        $this->data->recipientName = $recipientName;
        $this->data->recipientEmail = $recipientEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function attach(string $path, string $filename): self
    {
        $this->data->attach[$path] = $filename;
        return $this;
    }

    public function send(string $fromName = "", string $fromEmail = ""): bool
    {
        $fromName = $fromName !== "" ? $fromName : $_ENV['MAIL_FROM_NAME'];
        $fromEmail = $fromEmail !== "" ? $fromEmail : $_ENV['MAIL_FROM_EMAIL'];

        try 
        {
            $this->mail->SMTPSecure = $this->data->SMTPSecure;
            $this->mail->Subject = $this->data->subject;
            $this->mail->msgHTML($this->data->body);
            $this->mail->addAddress($this->data->recipientEmail,$this->data->recipientName);

            $this->mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);

            if (!empty($this->data->attach)) 
            {
                foreach ($this->data->attach as $path => $name) 
                {
                    $this->mail->addAttachment($path, $name);
                }
            }

            $this->mail->send();
            return true;
        } 
        
        catch (\Exception $exception) 
        {
            $this->error = $exception;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getError(): ?Exception
    {
        return $this->error;
    }
}
```

The file `.env`:

```
MAIL_HOST="mail.thproducoes.com"
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USER="sac@thproducoes.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD="secret"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Thiago Silva"
MAIL_FROM_EMAIL="sac@thproducoes.com"
```

The complete `[NameOfPage]Controller.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\Mail;
use Core\Controller;

class MailController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view("contacto.php", 
        [
            "lang" => "pt-br",
            "name" => "Thiago Silva",
        ]);
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $mail = new Mail("en");

        $orcamento = "orcamento@thproducoes.com";
        $sac = "sac@thproducoes.com";

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
        $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

        $isMailSent = $mail
            ->setSMTPSecure("tls")
            ->add("...", $sac)
            ->send($nome, $email);

        if (!$isMailSent) 
        {
            echo $mail->getError()->getMessage();
            return;
        }

        echo "...";
    }
}
```

I am suspecting that HostGator does not support it as I have just read https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1327.

Is it worth migrating from HostGator to Hostinger which offers a cheap Linux dedicated server that supports Composer?

Comment: Email fails for a million and one reasons, and throw TLS in there and you've got a million more. First, you should only assume that you have the ability to send email FROM an account that an IT person has explicitly granted. If you can't login, you don't have permission. This is sometimes IP based, with bad IPs blocked. Second, if TLS is involved, know that an HTTP cert isn't the same as an SMTP cert, so you have to debug that. Once you can connect, who you send FROM can cause a failure if that isn't viable because of blocklists, SPF, DKIM, etc.

Comment: This looks liek a straightforward SMTP block by your hosting provider. What happened when you tried the telnet and openssl command-line tests described in the troubleshooting guide? All hosts can support composer; if you can't run it on the server, you can always run it locally and upload all the files it generates along with your other scripts, but aside from that, I'd recommend checking with your host what their policy is on email, whether they require you to use their servers, and whether they can lift a block.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, so do you mean `->send($email)`? If I replace `$email` with the own e-mail?

Comment: @Synchro, I have just tested with the port 465 and the host `br726.hostgator.com.br`: 

`Trying 108.179.193.150... Connected to br726.hostgator.com.br. Escape character is '^]'.`

It seems OK.

Comment: OK, that's a good result with telnet, but you'll need to use openssl to see what it's saying on port 465.

Comment: @Synchro, the result from `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect br726.hostgator.com.br:465` is `CONNECTED(00000003)`.

Comment: You don't need `starttls` on port 465 as it's implicit, so try `openssl s_client -connect br726.hostgator.com.br:46`.

Comment: Ah, it could be that you're using `SMTPSecure = "tls"`; that won't work on port 465, you need `ssl` as the value for that.

Comment: I have just tested and it bizarrely worked. It turned that, without `$this->mail->SMTPAuth = true` and `$this->mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true` on the file `Mail.php`, and `->setSMTPSecure("ssl")` on the file `[NameOfPage]Controller.php`, the SMTP connection woulf fail. It also needed to be the host `br726.hostgator.com.br` instead.